# What's the difference between CTS and GTS?

Tags: android, compatibility, test-suite, cts

I'm familiar with CTS(Compatibility Test Suite). But recently I came across the term GTS, which as per my understanding is also a Google's compatibility test suite. But I don't have enough information regarding this. I googled for the difference between CTS and GTS but strangely and sadly didn't get anything specific. If anyone here knows about this, please tell me something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GTS is a list of requirements that the tablet must comply with in order for that tablet to be “Google Certified” and have permission to preload the Google Market Suite(“GMS”)

Just read this links for in details.

http://www.hatchmfg.com/gms-testing-and-certification/

https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In brief, CTS test suit focuses on the device hardware capacity whereas GTS cares about the device as a vehicle to consume Google Mobile Services (GMS) like Google Search, YouTube, Gmail, Chrome, Google Plus, Google Hangouts.

[This article](https://www.einfochips.com/blog/how-to-obtain-googles-gms-license-for-android-devices/) explains it better. From it, I quote the following:

> The Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) is a commercial-grade test suite (...) that validates the device’s software and hardware components.
>
> GMS refers to Google’s proprietary applications which are not part of the Android Open Source Project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @csabinho. Just applied it.